# Jinja: How does the null-master fallback example work?

Tags: flask, jinja2

The example code from the official jinja site:

```
{% if not standalone %}{% extends 'master.html' %}{% endif -%}
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<title>{% block title %}The Page Title{% endblock %}</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">  
{% block body %}
  <p>This is the page body.</p>
{% endblock %}
```

As I understand it, when standalone is true the following code is printed :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<title>{% block title %}The Page Title{% endblock %}</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">  
{% block body %}
  <p>This is the page body.</p>
{% endblock %}
```

And when standalone is false, this is printed :

```
{% if not standalone %}
 <<master.html's code>>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<title>{% block title %}The Page Title{% endblock %}</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">  
{% block body %}
  <p>This is the page body.</p>
{% endblock %}
```

This seems is very weird. I am clearly missing something obvious, what is it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The thing that is not immediately clear from the documentation is that when a template extends another template only the blocks in the child template that have a counterpart in the parent template(s) are rendered.  Everything else is dropped.

So in non-standalone mode:

```
{% if not standalone %}
{% only care about blocks also in "master.html" %}
{% endif %}
{# Everything below is ignored #}
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<title>{# The following will be rendered if master has a block named title. #}
{% block title %}The Page Title{% endblock %}
{# All the following will be ignored #}</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
{# This *may* be rendered, if master.html has a block named "body" #}
{% block body %}
  <p>This is the page body.</p>
{% endblock %}
```