# flask render_template returning blank page/empty response

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

I am programming a relatively straight forward web application in Flask. I have used flask for about a year now, and have never had this issue before.

In my '/create_user' function, the render_template response is always blank (even when I use the more explicit make_response function).

Here is the relevant view & jinja2 template:
https://gist.github.com/ianseyer/848332cea6f7ef1f69c2

Answer (score 2):

Strange!

extending `macros.html` was failing silently. Removing the extension solved the problem.

Comment: The issue was that since you were *extending* another template everything that is not inside a `block` was being dropped - this is the basis of the [Null-Master](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547547/jinja-how-does-the-null-master-fallback-example-work) trick.  (And this is also why it works when you remove the `extends`.)